# Checkboxes from another table yii2 and retaining checked values

Tags: php, yii2

I have three tables

```
--
-- Table structure for table `tbl_ticket`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_ticket` (
`id` int(9) NOT NULL,
  `complain_id` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `section_id` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `location_id` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `remarks` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `r_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `d_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `hd_user_username` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `hd_user_email` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `attachment` varchar(250) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `tbl_ticket`
--
ALTER TABLE `tbl_ticket`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `tbl_ticket`
--
ALTER TABLE `tbl_ticket`
MODIFY `id` int(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=2;

--
-- Table structure for table `tbl_ticket_complain`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_ticket_complain` (
`id` int(9) NOT NULL,
  `ticket_id` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `complain_id` varchar(250) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `tbl_ticket_complain`
--
ALTER TABLE `tbl_ticket_complain`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `tbl_ticket_complain`
--
ALTER TABLE `tbl_ticket_complain`
MODIFY `id` int(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=3;
```

and

```
   --
-- Table structure for table `tbl_complain_type`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_complain_type` (
`id` int(9) NOT NULL,
  `section_id` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `complains` varchar(250) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=20 ;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `tbl_complain_type`
--
ALTER TABLE `tbl_complain_type`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `tbl_complain_type`
--
ALTER TABLE `tbl_complain_type`
MODIFY `id` int(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=20;
```

I want to display the contents of `tbl_complain_type` , i.e, id and complains to be shown as check box in the view.
tbl_ticket  will be having multiple tbl_complain_type`.id as values and this is related through the table tbl_ticket_complain` .ticket_id =`tbl_ticket`.id . How can this be done in Yii2 views for CRUD ?

In controller I have made actionCreate like this

```
$model = new Ticket();
        $ticket_complain=new TicketComplain();
        $complain_type=ComplainType ::find ()->all();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
                    'complain_type'=>$complain_type,
                    'ticket_complain'=>$ticket_complain
            ]);
        }
```

and in View to display them as check box
I have added code like this

```
<?php 

$model->complains = $complain_type;

$list = $complain_type;

$options = \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($list, 'id', 'complains');


echo $form->field($model, 'complains')->checkboxList($options);

?>
```

The problem I am facing is retaining of the checkbox values and saving / updating the values . Also I am not sure whether to use checkBox instead of checkboxList , i.e,

```
$complains = [];
      if($complain_type ) {
         foreach($complain_type  as $complain) {
             $complains[] = $complain->complains;
             $id[]= $complain->id;
             echo $form->field($ticket_complain, 'id')
             ->checkBox(['label' => $complain->complains, 'uncheck' => null, 'selected' => true]);
         }
      }
```

Or let me simplify

How can I set model values as checkbox selected from from database and based on submitted values when submitted?

The relations between the three tables can be demostrated by this sql

```
SELECT  `tbl_ticket`.* , tbl_complain_type.complains  FROM tbl_ticket JOIN
tbl_ticket_complain ON tbl_ticket.id =tbl_ticket_complain.ticket_id JOIN
tbl_complain_type ON tbl_complain_type.id=tbl_ticket_complain.complain_id
```

Comment: Can u please help me understand your table structure?? I need to know about complain_id in tbl_ticket. Is that related to tbl_complain_type??

Comment: It doesnt have any relation to  tbl_complain_type

Comment: What I understand is you have multiple check box. You want to save the  selected values as comma separated values in the DB and then show it as selected values on update, which was selected on update or create. Right? You are not facing the problem in Saving the DB, but not retaining the selected values on update. Am I correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In model \app\models\Ticket.php add the following variable,

```
class Ticket extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public $complains_field; //A custom variable to hold the value of checkboxlist

    /*Remaining contents of Ticket model */

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['complains_field'], 'safe']
        ];
    }

    public function getComplains() //Relation between ticket & ticket_complain table
    {
        return $this->hasMany(TicketComplain::className(), ['ticket_id' => 'id']);
    }

    public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes){
        \Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->delete('tbl_ticket_complain', 'ticket_id = '.(int) $this->id)->execute(); //Delete existing value
        foreach ($this->complains_field as $id) { //Write new values
            $tc = new TicketComplain();
            $tc->ticket_id = $this->id;
            $tc->complain_id = $id;
            $tc->save();
        }
    }
}
```

In actionCreate() on the controller

```
$model = new Ticket();
$complain_type= ComplainType::find()->all();

if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
} 
else {
    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
        'complain_type'=>$complain_type
    ]);
}
```

In actionUpdate() on the controller

```
$model = $this->findModel($id);
$complain_type = ComplainType::find()->all();

//Retrieve the stored checkboxes
$model->complains_field = \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::getColumn(
    $model->getComplains()->asArray()->all(),
    'complain_id'
);

if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
} 
else {
    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
        'complain_type'=>$complain_type
    ]);
}
```

In View

```
<?php 
$options = \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($complain_type, 'id', 'complains');
echo $form->field($model, 'complains_field')->checkboxList($options, ['unselect'=>NULL]);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! One small addition: I think the "Retrieve the stored checkboxes" should be in the afterFind of the model instead of the controller

Answer (score 0):

All logic from controller moved to model. In controller only need do load() and save()

```php
/**
* special for form extend model. No good practice automatically load checkbox 
* records for each loaded model.
*/
class CwbrForm extends Cwbr
{

    /** @var int[] */
    public $chkList = [];
    public $oldchkList;

    public function rules()
    {
        return array_merge(parent::rules(),[
            ['chkList', 'each', 'rule' => ['integer']]
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getCwbrChk()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(CwbrChk::className(), ['cwbr_ide_id' => 'id']);
    }

    public function load($data, $formName = null)
    {
        $this->oldchkList = $this->chkList;
        if(!parent::load($data, $formName)){
            return false;
        }
        if(!$this->chkList){
            $this->chkList = [];
        }
        return true;
    }

    public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes)
    {
        parent::afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes);
        foreach(array_diff($this->chkList,$this->oldChkList) as $newChkId){
            $chk = new CwbrChk();
            $chk->cwbr_id = $this->id;
            $chk->chk_id = $newChkId;
            $chk->save();
        }

        CwbrChk::deleteAll([
            'chk_id' => array_diff($this->oldChkList,$this->chkList),
            'cwbr_id' => $this->id
        ]);

    }

    public function afterFind()
    {
        parent::afterFind();
        $this->chkList = ArrayHelper::getColumn($this->cwbrChk,'chk_id', false);
    }
}
```

View

```php
$options = [1 => 'One', 2 => 'Two'];
echo $form->field($model, 'chkList')->checkboxList($options, ['unselect'=>NULL]);
```